# How do I view the masked "commandOutput" in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using a Kubernetes@1 step in Azure Pipelines to view the logs of a specific pod.

The output of the kubectl command in the pipeline logs is not shown. Instead you only see a line "commandOutput".
How can I view the unmasked output?

Comment: Hi niko, any update? did my post help?

Comment: Hi @CeenoQi-MSFT, I appreciate the answer. Though I was not able to test the solution yet because there has been another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define kubectl task with a name

```
- task: Kubernetes@1
   name: TaskName
   displayName: displayname1
   inputs:
     connectionType: Kubernetes
     ***
```

I suppose that you could echo the kubernetes command output with script.

`echo $(TaskName.KubectlOutput)`